# Can FreeMarker write contents of directory to a template?

Tags: java, file-io, template-engine, freemarker

I'm trying to figure out how to use FreeMarker to generate a file like so:

```
The contents of /home/myuser/somedir are:
    blah.txt
    fizz.gif
    buzz.jpg
    widget.log
```

...from a template like so:

```
The contents of <%dir%> are:
    <%contents%>
```

I read the excellent Vogella tutorial on FreeMarker, but not really sure how to put this all together: once I query the directory for its contents, how do I add each item to this list of `<%contents%>`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Last time I saw the Vogella tutorial it was full of mistakes and inelegant FTL solutions... Not that it matters regarding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeMarker templates can only display what you give to them through the data-model (aka. the template context). After all, a template is an MVC View, not a general purpose program. So, create a `List<String>` before you call FreeMarker, call it `dirContents` or something, put that into the data-model, also the directory name, and call it `dirName`, and then do something like:

```
<p>${dirName}:</p>
<ul>
  <#list dirContents as entry>
    <li>${entry}</li>
  </#list>
</ul>
```